# link a Kiln commit to a fogbugz ticket

Tags: fogbugz, kiln

I have a kiln repo and a FB system. They are integrated, so that when I commit something, if I include "Case 333" in the commit message, it will link to Fogbugz ticket 333.

How do I do this from the other side? If I forgot to add the case number, how do I make  the connection from the fogbugz side? I looked at the fogbugz help, and they only tell you how to do the Case 333 method, which doesn't help after you've already committed, because you can't edit commit messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you can do this under Kiln. When you view the commit, you can view the cases it's linked to. This allows you to add a case. I assumed that you would do it from fogbugz, but evidently, all information goes from kiln to fogbugz not vice versa...

I'm going to leave this open in case anyone has a way to actually do this from fogbugz, just for completeness.